Prove that $g_n = \sup_{j\geq n}|f_j-f|$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable.
My Question
Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots$ be real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$. Suppose $\mu$ is finite and $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere. Prove that $g_n = \sup_{j\geq n}|f_j-f|$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable.
Background
I am reading the proof of Egoroff's Theorem. Although I am able to understand most of the proof, I could not see why the function $g_n$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable; that is, why the set $\{x\in X:\sup_{j\geq n}|f_j(x)-f(x)<t|\}\in\mathscr{A}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$? As you can see in the proof below, it implicitely says that each $B_k$ must belong to $\mathscr{A}$, which means $g_n$ must be $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, but without proof.
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out!
The Egoroff's Theorem with Proof

Egoroff's Theorem$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots$ be real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$. If $\mu$ is finite and if $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere, then for each positive number $\epsilon$ there is a subset $B$ of $X$ that belongs to $\mathscr{A}$, satisfies $\mu(B^c)<\epsilon$, and is such that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $B$.


Proof$\quad$ Let $\epsilon$ be a positive number, and for each $n$ let $g_n = \sup_{j\geq n}|f_j-f|$. It is easy to check that each $g_n$ is finite almost everywhere. The sequence $\{g_n\}$ converges to $0$ almost everywhere, and so in measure. Hence for each positive integer $k$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\left\{x\in X:g_n(x)>\frac{1}{k}\right\}=0$; that is, for each $\epsilon>0$ and for each positive integer $k$ there is a positive integer $n_k$ such that
\begin{align*}
    \mu\left(\left\{x\in X:g_{n_k}(x)>\frac{1}{k}\right\}\right)<\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}.
\end{align*}
Define sets $B_1,B_2,\dots$ by $B_k = \left\{x\in X:g_{n_k}(x)\leq\frac{1}{k}\right\}$, and let $B = \bigcap_kB_k$. The set $B$ satisfies
\begin{align*}
    \mu(B^c) = \mu\left(\bigcup_kB_k^c\right) \leq \sum_k\mu\left(B_k^c\right) < \sum_k\frac{\epsilon}{2^k} = \epsilon.
\end{align*}
If $\delta$ is a positive number and if $k$ is a positive integer such that $\frac{1}{k}<\delta$, then, since $B\subseteq B_k$,
\begin{align*}
    |f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq g_{n_k}(x) \leq \frac{1}{k} < \delta
\end{align*}
holds for all $x$ in $B$ and all positive integers $n$ such that $n\geq n_k$; thus $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $B$.


Supremum of measurable functions is measurable.

@Kakashi Thanks a lot! This is not a good question. My bad.

You can write the $g_n$ as a pointwise limit of measurable functions. Namley, define recursively $h_0=\vert f_n - f\vert$ and $h_{k+1}=\max{ \vert f_{k+n+1}-f \vert, h_k }$, or more easily $h_k = \sup_{n\leq j\leq k} \vert f-f_j \vert$. Now, the maximum of two measurable functions is measurable (as we can write $\max{ f,g } = (f+g+\vert f -g\vert)/2$).  Furthermore, we have $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} h_k = g_n$ and thus, $g_n$ is the pointwise limit of measurable functions and therefore measurable.
